# Can VBA attempt to assign to a cell a formula that is too long?

Tags: vba, excel

I am on Windows, if that matters. This code seems to attempt to assign a formula that is too long:

```
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("SegmentValues_1").ListColumns("Change").DataBodyRange.Formula = "=IFERROR(IF(INDEX(SegmentValues_" & (ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.count - 2) & "[CODE_ZONE],MATCH([@Modules],SegmentValues_" & (ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.count - 2) & "[Modules],0))=0,""Last total was ZERO"",([@CODE_ZONE]-INDEX(SegmentValues_" & (ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.count - 2) & "[CODE_ZONE],MATCH([@Modules],SegmentValues_" & (ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.count - 2) & "[Modules],0)))/INDEX(SegmentValues_" & (ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.count - 2) & "[CODE_ZONE],MATCH([@Modules],SegmentValues_" & (ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.count - 2) & "[Modules],0)))),""Did not exist previously"")"
```

Is such a thing possible? If so, how to solve it?

Comment: Looks like you have one too many closing brackets near the end - it should be: `"[Modules],0))),""Did not exist previously"")"` and not `"[Modules],0)))),""Did not exist previously"")"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The long formulas work in Excel VBA quite well. Take a look at this 24 nested `IF()`:

```
Sub TestMe()

    Range("A1").Formula = "=IF(1=1,IF(1=1,IF(1=1,IF(1=1,IF(1=1,IF(1=1,IF(1=1,IF(1=1," & _
            "IF(1=1,IF(1=1,IF(1=1,IF(1=1,IF(1=1,IF(1=1,IF(1=1,IF(1=1,IF(1=1,IF(1=1," & _
            "IF(1=1,IF(1=1,IF(1=1,IF(1=1,IF(1=1,IF(1=1,IF(1=1,IF(1=1,IF(1=1,IF(1=1," & _
            "IF(1=1,IF(1=1,IF(1=1,IF(1=1,IF(1=1,IF(1=1,IF(1=1,IF(1=1,IF(1=1,IF(1=1," & _
            "IF(1=1,IF(1=1,IF(1=1,IF(1=1,IF(1=1,IF(1=1,IF(1=1," & _
            "IF(1=1,2))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))"

End Sub
```

It is translated really well into Excel. Thus, take a good look at your formula, the problem should be there.